# How To Add menu when rightclick on dynamic grid in ext.net?

Tags: c#-4.0, ext.net

How To Add menu when rightclick on dynamic grid in ext.net ?

I Had Tried As Below In RowExpander, It is Showing That ItemContextMenu  does not support in RowExpander, Please Help me ?

```
<ext:RowExpander runat="server">
                    <Loader runat="server" DirectMethod="#{DirectMethods}.GetGrid" Mode="Component">
                        <LoadMask ShowMask="true" />
                        <Params>
                            <ext:Parameter Name="RecordId" Value="this.record.getId()" Mode="Raw" />
                        </Params>   
                    </Loader>

                <DirectEvents>
                        <BeforeExpand OnEvent="BeforeExpand" Success="setRaw(response, result, el, type, action, extraParams);" Before="return !record.cached;">
                            <EventMask ShowMask="true" Target="CustomTarget" CustomTarget="={gridRecords.body}" />

                            <ExtraParams>
                                <%--<ext:Parameter Name="company" Value="record.data['company']" Mode="Raw" />
                                <ext:Parameter Name="id" Value="record.id" Mode="Raw" />
                                <ext:Parameter Name="index" Value="rowIndex" Mode="Raw" /> --%> 
                                 <ext:Parameter Name="RecordId" Value="record.get('RecordId')" Mode="Raw" />
                            </ExtraParams>
                        </BeforeExpand>
                    </DirectEvents>
                   <Listeners>
                          <ItemContextMenu Handler="e.preventDefault(); #{mnuView}.showAt(e.getXY());" />
                    </Listeners>

                 </ext:RowExpander>
```

Answer (score 0):

RowExpander doesn't have an ItemContextMenu event. You should define it for a child GridPanel itself.

It is being discussed in greater details in these forum threads:

- [Forum thread #1](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?60076)
- [Forum thread #2](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?60101)